# How do I compare two values from two vectors and then update the vector values in C++?

Tags: c++, vector

Thanks for the help on the previous code, guys! I am now expanding the previous query to include this code: I am having the issue of no output from the for loops and if statements. I have to compare strings in two vectors and find if one is a subset of the other; if there is a subset, I must remove it. (the two vectors are actually identical...this is essentially comparing all elements within a vector against each other). Any guidance would be very much appreciated!

```
 //headers: iostream, vector
 //namespace std 
 //main function

//each vector already has content (read from a file) stored in them. Both vectors hold         the same elements.

int c,j; string first_sequence, second_sequence;
vector<string>::iterator ivector1; vector<string>::iterator ivector2;
vector<string> sequence_1; vector<string> sequence_2; vector<string> header;

 //comparison of sequences within each element of vectors

size_t location,x,y,k,s;

k = sequence_1.size(); 
s = sequence_2.size();
for(ivector1 = sequence_1.begin(); ivector1< sequence_1.end(); ivector1++){
 for(ivector2= sequence_2.begin();ivector2<sequence_2.end(); ivector2++){
    *ivector1 = first_sequence; *ivector2 = second_sequence;    

    if(ivect1 != ivect2){
        x = first_sequence.size();
        y = second_sequence.size();

        if(x > y){
            location = first_sequence.find(second_sequence);
                                if (location != -1){
                                    cout << "Deleting the sequence with id: <"     << *ivector2 << endl;
                    sequence_2.erase(ivector2); *ivector2 = "gone";
                                     }  


                }   else if (y > x) {
            location = second_sequence.find(first_sequence);
                                if (location != -1){                             
                    cout << "Deleting the sequence with id: <"<< *ivector1 << endl;
                    sequence_1.erase(ivector1); *ivector1 = "gone";

                                    }   

                         }
    }
 }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: In a `vector<int>`, it shouldn't let you write `*ilist2 = "gone";`.

Comment: "gone" is actually 0. Thanks for the catch, Ben! The program still doesn't show me the values after the for loop, though.

Comment: BTW, preincrement `++ilist1` can be faster than postincrement `ilist1++` (at best it is equal, depending on how good the optimizer is)

Comment: Is it just me, or does the title not seem to have anything to do with the question?

Comment: @user3079139 As this is your first question I should point out that it is unwise to alter your code excessively once answers have been posted. The 2 answers below now are not remotely associated with your original source code of your initial question. Furthermore, your NEW vectors are empty

Comment: @mathematician1975 Please forgive my ignorance (sleep deprivation has made me careless). I am updating the code to show that I have read input from a file into both vectors...this I have tested and know that the original contents of each vector are there. Thanks for your catch!

Comment: @mathematician1975 Should I re-post this as a separate question?

Comment: I only mentioned it for the next time you post a question. What would probably be helpful though is to edit your new code with regards to indentation. The tidier the formatting is the easier it is to read. The easier to read, the more likely to get a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In every single loop, you're assigning the value of the iterators to the strings first_sequence and second_sequence. You're not ever using the values in the vectors themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You get no output because none of the elements in vector1 are larger than the lowest value you have inserted into vector2. Therefore this `if` condition that you test

```
  if (*ilist1 > *ilist2)
```

is never satisfied, hence no `cout` statement will run. I am willing to bet that if you change it to

```
 if (*ilist1 < *ilist2)
```

you will see output to the terminal/screen. 3 is always < 4.

Answer (score 0):

You are only ever testing if values from vector 1 are bigger than values from vector 2.

Your code is testing:

```
1 > 4
1 > 5
1 > 6
2 > 4
2 > 5
2 > 6
3 > 4
3 > 5
3 > 6
```

None of these are true, so nothing's getting displayed.

Comment: Thanks for all the input! I have updated my query to address the issues of vectors<string> and a comparison of their elements (the vectors are identical...so it could be thought of comparing all elements within a single vector against each other).

Comment: ivect1 and ivect2 never get initialised, I'm guessing they are also meant to be ivector1 and ivector2. That needs further editing so the variables all make sense. I'd also advise up-voting answers that help ;-)

Comment: @ splrs It says that I have to have 15 reputation? I would love to up-vote, though!